# Ubuntu 18.04 fails to boot up

Tags: boot, 16.04, 18.04, upgrade

I upgraded to 18.04 from 16.04 two weeks ago. Everything has been running fine until now.

I was logged in. When I returned after leaving the laptop idle for 1/2 hour the login box had an extra message (now no longer visible) something about memory (my laptop has not run out of memory). I could not get any response and had to power down. On powering up the purple screen goes to black and hangs as below.
Any suggestions?

I am not permitted to attach an image so have to (painfully) type what I see in the black screen (it appears single spaced on the screen but to stop it wrapping have made it double spaced):

```
/dev/sdal: clean, 776654/7577600 files, 28795982/30292224 blocks
[ OK ] Created slice User Slice of gdm.
       Starting User Manager for UID 125...
[ OK ] Started Session c1 of user gdm.
[ OK ] Started User Manager for UID 125.
       Starting Daemon for power management...
[ OK ] Started Daemon for power management.
[ OK ] Started LSB: Speech Dispatcher.
[FAILED] Failed to start LSB: Start the GNUstep distributed object mapper.
See 'systemct1 status gdomap.service' for details.
[ OK ] Started LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB.
[ OK ] Started LSB: automatic crash report generation.
[ OK ] Started Hold until boot process finishes up.
```

Answer (score 1):

/dev/sdal was full
Had to get it by going down through the 
grub menu (hold down shift on start up),
selecting Advanced Options,
selecting Recovery mode,
selecting root,
deleted just enough unwanted files allowed me to reboot
and continue from there.